# Can't get .NET Standard 2.0 installed

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I'm trying to create a .NET Standard 2.0 project, however on the project properties page it only has options up to .NET Standard 1.6. I went to Visual Studio > Tools > Extensions and Updates > Updates > Product Updates and upgraded Visual Studio 2017 to the latest version (15.5.4.)

I also downloaded / installed the .Net Core 2.0 SDKs from both of these urls:

https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.0-download.md

https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/windows?utm_expid=.-Fmi9Q05Ry2oXQgdtPElHw.0&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.talkingdotnet.com%2Fwhats-new-in-net-standard-2%2F#windowscmd

For good measure I even rebooted, yet still no .NET Standard 2.0 option. What gives?

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>dotnet --info .NET Command Line Tools (2.1.4)
>
> Product Information:  Version:            2.1.4  Commit SHA-1 hash: 
>   5e8add2190
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     Windows  OS Version:  10.0.16299 
>   OS Platform: Windows  RID:         win10-x64  Base Path:   C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\
>
> Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
>
> Version  : 2.0.5   Build    :
>   17373eb129b3b05aa18ece963f8795d65ef8ea54

Answer (score 9):

It turns out that someone had put a global.json file at the root of our repo that was hard-coding the SDK to a 1.x preview version. Once I updated that to 2.1.4, I started getting the .NET Standard 2.0 project option!

Comment: Get used to it. Microsoft likes to not only move the cheese, but hide it just to challenge developers. They now want to hide *using* statements inside other files and even within the project file itself.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Windows "App and Features" or "Install and Remove Programs" and make sure you have .NETCore SDK (x64) and or (x86).  You may have only installed the (x64) and not the (x86). Try changing your project target to x64 and x86.

Refer to this article for installing .NET Standard 2.0

https://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/2017/12/13/how-to-install-net-standard-2-0/

Comment: That's the exact article I followed. As mentioned, I updated my Visual Studio and installed .NET Core 2.0...

Comment: 2021 - That article doesn't exist any more

Comment: Here is the updated link: https://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/2017/12/13/how-to-install-net-standard-2-0/

Answer (score 3):

When I click on "Install Other Frameworks..." in project properties, it takes me to this page:

https://web.archive.org/web/20230204054521/https://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/2017/12/13/how-to-install-net-standard-2-0/

And it appears that the installer on that page (`dotnet-sdk-2.1.4-windows-x64-installer`) is different than the one in the other links you have tried.

Also, be sure that all instances of Visual Studio are closed when you install the SDK.

Comment: Yeah I tried that one probably 10 times, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: One thing that helped me was to put the folder containing dotnet.exe on the path.

Comment: Updated link: https://www.thebestcsharpprogrammerintheworld.com/2017/12/13/how-to-install-net-standard-2-0/