# Visual studio 2017 cannot target .Net standard 2.0, but Visual studio 2019 can?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I open the same Xamarin.Forms project on both Visual studio 2017 and 2019.

[image: Visual studio 2019]

[image: Visual studio 2017]

On my Visual studio 2019 can i target 2.0, but when i try to open it on my Visual studio 2017 the option is blank.

There is no *global.json* file present in my project root folder.

My colleagues can all target 2.0 except my development environment.

I tried to install multiple frameworks that correspondent with the correct .NET Standard version (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).

I tried multiple uninstalls and install, also tried to install an older version of Visual studio 2017 and then update it.

These are all my installed SDK's so far:

[image]

Can someone suggest why i cannot target the corresponding .NET Standard version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48449553/cant-get-net-standard-2-0-installed

Comment: I saw that post before and tried all three suggestions all with no success...

Comment: It sounds like installing the VS2017 update for that specific version didn't also install the .NET Core 2.0 SDK. You can download that from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download .

Comment: which one should fix this ? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.0

Comment: You could install it from nuget , search and install `NETStandard.Library` . In addition ,since it works fine on VS 2019 , we could better update the IDE to the latest version . It will has some unknown issue to open a project (which created by the new IDE)on old version IDE .

Comment: yeah but i the project does not work on android in VS2019 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860332/xamarin-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-implementation-found-for-void-crc6469?noredirect=1#comment105910943_59860332)

Comment: Delete the folder bin and obj both in Android project and share proejct . Then clean and rebuild it .